# C#code in 32feet, hard to understand 'Stream peer = (Stream)state;' Abstract class in brackets, what does it mean?

Tags: c#, bluetooth, abstract-class, 32feet

I recently changed from PHP to learn C#. I am trying to code a project for Bluetooth communication with framework 32feet. 
How to understand  '(Stream)' in the code below? Thanks in advance!

```
   private void ReadMessagesToEnd_Runner(object state)
    {
        Stream peer = (Stream)state;
        ReadMessagesToEnd(peer);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called [type casting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173105.aspx). It changes a variables type (including the whole mess that happens if it *wasn't* actually of that type.). You should read a good book or tutorial on C# before you continue.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague, but I'll try my best to explain.

All classes are derived from `Object` in C#, thus any `Object` can be cast to any type.  All the `(Stream)state` is doing above is taking the object `state` passed into the method and turning it into a `Stream` object.

If your question was actually asking what the `Stream` class is, please direct your attention to the Google search bar and type "C# Stream".